# Foursquare API - Tastes

Tags: api, rest, foursquare

When I try to send a GET request to Foursquare API below, I get "No matching endpoint." error.

I have validated my tokens and everything seems normal. Any advices?

REQUEST URL

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/tastes
```

RESPONSE MESSAGE

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 404,
        "errorType": "endpoint_error",
        "errorDetail": "No matching endpoint"
    },
    "notifications": [
        {
            "type": "notificationTray",
            "item": {
                "unreadCount": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "response": {}
}
```

Comment: tastes is a response, not a user_id

Comment: I'm putting my USER_ID information to there @stark . Just didn't want to expose my USER_ID so I've copied the api endpoint from the documents.

Answer (score 1):

FoursquareAPI twitter account has told me that I needed to pass m=foursquare in addition to version information.

The correct endpoint information is like

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/tastes?oauth_token=TOKEN&v=20150420&m=foursquare
```

The detailed information about v and m parameters are below.
https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning